# Dynamically setting Doctrine EntityManager connection before each request in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I am working on a Symfony2 site that will host many sites, and each site will have its own database. I have implemented a service uses reflection to change connection parameters (username, password, dbname) on the 'client' entity manager. I'm not sure how to trigger this service before FOSUserBundle invokes its authentication services. I tried to create a Symfony2 Request event listener, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
class RequestListener {
    private $clientSiteContext;

    function __construct($clientSiteContext) {
        $this->clientSiteContext = $clientSiteContext;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        if ($event->getRequestType() == HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST) {
            $this->clientSiteContext->resetClientEntityManager();
        }
    }
}
```

resetClientEntityManager() implementation

```
public function resetClientEntityManager() {
    /** @var $doctrine \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry */
    $doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');

    $dbConfig = $this->getConnectionParams();
    $dbalServiceName = sprintf('doctrine.dbal.%s_connection', 'client');
    $clientEmName = 'client';

    $connection = $this->container->get($dbalServiceName);
    $connection->close();

    $refConn = new \ReflectionObject($connection);
    $refParams = $refConn->getProperty('_params');
    $refParams->setAccessible('public');

    $params = $refParams->getValue($connection);
    $params['dbname'] = $dbConfig['dbname'];
    $params['user'] = $dbConfig['user'];
    $params['host'] = $dbConfig['host'];
    $params['password'] = $dbConfig['password'];
    $params['driver'] = $dbConfig['driver'];
    $params['charset'] = 'UTF8';

    $refParams->setAccessible('private');
    $refParams->setValue($connection, $params);

    $doctrine->resetEntityManager($clientEmName);
}
```

Can someone advise how I can get this Listener to get call once for every page request, and for it to affect the Entity Manager that FOSUserBundle uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to have this before any of the Kernel events. Probably the best place for it would be to put it somewhere within your AppKernel (`app/AppKernel.php`) itself.

You could probably take it in to getBundles(), or add something like:

```
public function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    resetClientEntityManager();
}
```

I haven't tested that out, but it should do the trick. boot() is the function where the container is initialized, so you should be making the switch right after the container is initialized, before anything else has a chance to do anything.

Comment: This would be perfect, but resetClientEntityManager() depends on the 'request' object from the container, but the system says throws an InactiveScopeException: You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request"). So I need to put the method somewhere after the Request object is accessible but before any Doctrine dependencies are requested.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that all of the services (including Doctrine) are set up before the Request is made. You'd have to add a hook to the Request, change the settings and reload all relevant data in FOSUserBundle manually.